# How can I justify text with Flutter markdown?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I started using flutter markdown, however I'd like to justify the content, and I couldn't until now.

I tried using a `Center` and `Alignment` but didn't work.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_markdown/flutter_markdown.dart';

class OutsideBankHourDescription extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    String text =
        "Antecipações em __horários__ bancários acontecem em 1h na média. __Fora do horário bancário__ o saldo estará em sua conta __no dia seguinte.__";

    return Expanded(
      child: Container(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: Markdown(
          styleSheet: MarkdownStyleSheet.fromTheme(Theme.of(context)),
          data: text,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's **not available for now** to change text alignment in *flutter_markdown 0.2.0*.
You must contact the authors of this plugin to request this feature.

But **if you need fast fix**, you can add `textAlign: TextAlign.center` attribute in source code of this file: https://github.com/flutter/flutter_markdown/blob/master/lib/src/builder.dart

Line of code: **345**

```
mergedTexts.add(new RichText(text: mergedSpan, textAlign: TextAlign.center));
```

Result:

[image: flutter_markdown alignment center]

For more elegant way you must clone git repository of this plugin, attach to your project directly and work to add text alignment feature on your own.

Comment: code github crashed

Answer (score 14):

It becomes possible to set up proper text alignment with [flutter_markdown](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_markdown).

```
    var style = MarkdownStyleSheet(
        textAlign: WrapAlignment.center,
        h1Align: WrapAlignment.center,
      );
    Markdown(
        styleSheet: style,
        data: '# header1 is center-aligned\ntext body is also center-aligned'
    );
```

You can customized your styles with all the other optional parameters provided by MarkdownStyleSheet class.

Comment: The alignment doesn't seem to work for strings that have formats, though, like bolds or hyperlinks... at least for me anyway, in v0.3.4.

Comment: The alignment styles shall work regardless of the formats such as bolds or hyperlinks. Can you paste a code snippet so other people can also look into it and maybe figure out a solution?

Comment: Not sure why myself. I did exactly like you did except with `MarkdownBody`. The string is something like this (bold text at the end): "Lorem ipsum dolor quis elit duis ullamco aute ut. Magna ullamco duis **tempor nulla**."

Comment: Oh, I think it happened if the text is too long that it wrapped the text to multiple lines. If I used shorter text that fits in one line, it works.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me using `MarkdownBody`.

```dart
MarkdownBody(
  data: data,
  fitContent: false,
  styleSheet: MarkdownStyleSheet(
    textAlign: WrapAlignment.center,
  ),
)
```

`fitContent` is misleading, but setting it to false stretches the text to fit the parent. If you're using `MarkdownBody` in a stretched-width column, this seems to do the trick.